# Cannot retrieve json data using Drupal services module with Bluehost

Tags: json, service

I am unable to view my endpoint in drupal using bluehost. I have used acquia local hosting and the data is viewable just fine via http request and through command line using curl. When I set up the site with drupal on Bluehost I receive a blank page.

with end point test:
http://parentstalkaddiction.com/test/node.json
gives me nothing

Can anyone please tell me what I might be doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a PHP version issue. Bluehost seems to be on PHP 5.2.x and the services module uses functionality that requires PHP 5.3.x.

There is an issue open for this: https://drupal.org/node/2003396

If you don't mind applying a patch, you can do so to make it work with Bluehost's version of PHP:
https://drupal.org/files/ServicesRESTServerFactory.inc_.patch